# Getting data with axios but unable to display with html

Tags: reactjs, api, state

I am trying to display a list of towns or departments from an API, I can display the data with console.log but when i put it in html its not working.
here's my ListTown.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "./api";


function ListTowns() {
  const DEPARTEMENTS = "/get/location/departements";
  const [departements, setDepartements] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await api.get(DEPARTEMENTS).then((response) => {
        setDepartements(response.data.data.departements);
      });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {departements.map((dep) => {
          <li key={dep.id}>{dep.name}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ListTowns;
```

console log (dep.name) gives this result [console.log(dep.name)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o1E9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return the data out of your `.map` method, so right now it's returning `undefined` for each element.

```js
{departements.map((dep) => {
  return <li key={dep.id}>{dep.name}</li>;
})}
```